# Should I horizontally flip a selfie image before posting online?

Tags: photo-editing, self-portrait

I took a picture of myself simply using my phone's rear camera selfie style. Obviously my face is flipped. So should I post it as is, or should I flip it first since everyone else sees my face that way?

Comment: Leave is as it is. It needs to be the way other people would see you (unless you simply want to admire yourself).

Comment: You "should" nothing. But you can do as you like.

Comment: Does it look like your face in the mirror? If not, it's not flipped.

Comment: I don't think it's "obvious" to some of us that your face is flipped. Try taking a selfie with text (or other easily recognized object) behind you. You'll soon discover that the camera records text so that it can be read with no postprocessing.

Answer (score 3):

Your face is not flipped when you take a selfie.  The preview is flipped to make it easier to use, but the image captured is not on any phone I've seen.  Both the front and rear facing cameras work just like normal cameras.  If someone was looking at you taking the photo and held it up in front of you, what they see in the photo would match what they see in real life.

If you want to flip it for some reason, you are welcome to do so.  There isn't any rule against reversing an image and it is sometimes done for different artistic reasons, but it's entirely your call.

If you are just worried about it being backwards because you had the display facing you when the camera was facing you.  That simply isn't how it works, so you don't have to worry about accounting for it.

Comment: selfies taken with the front camera are usually flipped because the live view imitates the mirror behavior for convenience. not that this is particularly important... and the OP said it was rear camera anyway.

Comment: @szulat - The preview is reversed, but not the actual captured photo, at least not on any phone I've seen.  Regardless of which camera I use, every phone I've ever had produces images that are aligned according to the sensor when saved or displayed to others (for video conferencing for example).

Comment: It's probably worth noting that the preview is reversed but the saved photo is not.

Comment: Some phones / camera apps not only display the preview flipped, but the resulting image is still flipped.

For example on my Galaxy A5 the official camera app flips the preview but un-flips when saving, but in apps like WhatsApp the resulting image remains flipped.  I believe some phones leave the image flipped in the official camera app too.

I've noticed this before and it has seemed wrong to me but there you go.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone sees your face the same as the camera does, YOU are the only one who sees it backwards when you look in the mirror. You have a perception of the way you look based on the way you see it in mirror and the way your brain thinks you look. Your perception of how you look is very different than how you actually look or how you are seen by others.

[Why You Look Different in Photos Than You Do in the Mirror](https://gizmodo.com/5661253/giz-explains-why-you-look-different-in-photos-than-you-do-in-the-mirror)

[Sorry, You Don’t Look The Way You Think You Do](http://www.sciencealert.com/you-don-t-look-the-way-you-think-you-do-science-reveals)

If you want to post photos that represent how you actually look then post the photos as they were taken. If you want to express yourself as something different than how people see you or how you want to be seen, then do that. But you should understand the difference.